# Как конвертировать Byte [] созданный QRCodeGenerator в изображение

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, qrcode, qr

Для генерации QR coda использую библиотеку QRCoder.
Генерирую данной библиотекой QR код и сохраняю его в виде Byte[] в базу данных MySQL (поле с типом mediumblob):

```
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(QRtext, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
Byte[] QRbytes = qrCodeData.GetRawData(QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);
```

Получается массив как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда потом я пытаюсь конвертировать данный Byte[] в изображение получается, что-то несуразное:

```
<img src="@String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(Model.QRcodeBytes))" width="150" height="150" />
```

После некоторых экспериментов пришел к такому варианту - после того как мы сохранили qr код в виде байт массива в БД, для его корректного вывода в изображение восстановливаю снова объект `QRCodeData` из этого байт массива, затем из восстановленного объект `QRCodeData` генерирую `Bitmap` объект, а потом это `Bitmap` объект снова конвертирую в Byte[] и отправляю его на фронт, где генерирую изображение ))

```
public static Byte [] GenerateQRcodeFile(string fio, string dateBirth, string QRtext, string typeFile, string wayPath)
        {
            //Generates QR code files
            QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
            QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(QRtext, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);

            Byte[] QRbytes = qrCodeData.GetRawData(QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);

          

           return QRbytes;
        }

        public static Bitmap CreateBitmapFromBytes(Byte[] bytesQRcode)
        {
            QRCodeData qrCodeDataSave = new QRCodeData(bytesQRcode, QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);
            QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeDataSave);
            Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);

            return qrCodeImage;
        }

        public static Byte[] BitmapToBytes(Bitmap img)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
QRcodeServices.BitmapToBytes(QRcodeServices.CreateBitmapFromBytes(friend.ByteQrcode))
```

В общем вариант такой себе, но другого пока не нашел.
Подскажите кто знает, как это сделать проще и правильнее?

Comment: у них же прямо в ридми написано: https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder

Comment: @PashaPash, там описано как создать изображение из объекта ```QRCode```, а у меня Byte[]

Comment: ну так не доставайте byte[] - работайте с Base64QRCode, как в ответе

Comment: @PashaPash, я в БД пишу и храню в виде mediumblob, т.е. как  byte[]

Comment: отписался под ответом - из этих byte[] можно обратно QRCodeData собрать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Ваш код

var imgType = Base64QRCode.ImageType.Jpeg;
Base64QRCode qrCode = new Base64QRCode(qrCodeData);
string qrCodeImageAsBase64 = qrCode.GetGraphic(20,Color.Black, Color.White, true, imgType);
```

Источник: [Wiki QRCoder (github)](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/wiki/Advanced-usage---QR-Code-renderers#23-base64qrcode-renderer-in-detail)

Comment: Это вы приводите код как создать изображение из объекта QRCode, а у меня Byte[]

Comment: я в базу данных пишу ```Byte[] QRbytes = qrCodeData.GetRawData(QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);```, а потом когда понадобится извлекаю

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir храните в байтах, потом доставайте и делайте из них `new QRCodeData(rawBytes, ...)` и дальше через Base64QRCode. Или храните строку `qrCodeImageAsBase64` вместо байт в базе

Comment: @PashaPash, мне на фронт нужно передать байт массив, а Base64QRCode возвращает Base64QRCode

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir вам на фронт надо передать строку в base64 - вы же сейчас руками байты конвертите. уберите вызов Convert.ToBase64String и рендерите там qrCodeImageAsBase64 из ответа